# Rotate List by K places

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, linked-list

I am trying to solve the question at

:https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-list/

### Question:

> Given a linked list, rotate the list to the right by k places, where k
>   is non-negative.
>
> Example 1:
>
> - Input:  `1->2->3->4->5->NULL`, `k = 2`
> - Output: `4->5->1->2->3->NULL`
>
> Explanation:
>
> - rotate 1 steps to the right: `5->1->2->3->4->NULL`
> - rotate 2 steps to the right: `4->5->1->2->3->NULL`

```
//public class ListNode
//{
//    public int val;
//    public ListNode next;
//    public ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
//}



//k = number of places
//head =Given Linked List

    public  ListNode RotateRight(ListNode head, int k) {
        if (k > 0 && head != null) {
            ListNode tail = head,
            RotatedList = null,
            kthnode = head,
            kthPrevNode = head;
            int listLength = 0;
            while (tail != null) {
                listLength += 1;
                tail = tail.next;
            }

            k = k % listLength;
            if (k == 0 || listLength == 0) {
                return head;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < listLength - k; i++) {

                kthPrevNode = kthnode;

                kthnode = kthnode.next;

            }

            RotatedList = kthnode;
            kthPrevNode.next = null;
            while (kthnode.next != null) {
                kthnode = kthnode.next;
            }

            kthnode.next = head;
            return RotatedList;

        }

        return head;
    }
}
}
```

I have passed all test cases but I am looking to improve code efficiency and time complexity,Kindly let me know if there are any bad practices as well

Answer (score 7):

> ```
>         if (k > 0 && head != null) {
>             ...
>             return RotatedList;
>
>         }
>
>         return head;
> ```

would be clearer (and more consistent with the other special case) as

```
        if (k <= 0 || head == null) {
            return head;
        }

        ...
        return RotatedList;
```

(although really if `k < 0` I think it should `throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(k))`).

---

> ```
>             ListNode tail = head,
>             RotatedList = null,
>             kthnode = head,
>             kthPrevNode = head;
> ```

Most of these don't need to be declared so early. Declaring variables as late as possible (and, more generally, in the narrowest scope possible) helps to reduce cognitive load when maintaining the code.

---

> ```
>             int listLength = 0;
>             while (tail != null) {
>                 listLength += 1;
>                 tail = tail.next;
>             }
> ```

This would be worth factoring out as a separate method `Length(ListNode head)`.

---

> ```
>             k = k % listLength;
>             if (k == 0 || listLength == 0) {
>                 return head;
>             }
> ```

This is sort-of buggy. If `listLength == 0` then `k % listLength` will throw an `ArithmeticException`. *However*, you can never reach here in that case, because `listLength == 0` is equivalent to `head == null`, and that was already handled in the first special case. To remove confusion, delete `|| listLength == 0`. If you want to validate that condition, insert `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(listLength > 0);` *before* the `%` line.

---

> ```
>             for (int i = 0; i < listLength - k; i++) {
>
>                 kthPrevNode = kthnode;
>
>                 kthnode = kthnode.next;
>
>             }
> ```

It's not actually necessary to track two nodes here. The invariant is that `kthPrevNode.next == kthnode`, so it suffices to track `kthPrevNode`.

Also, the blank lines seem excessive to me.

---

> ```
>             RotatedList = kthnode;
> ```

It's conventional in C# that local variable names start with a lower case letter, so to avoid confusion I would rename `RotatedList` to `rotatedList` (or perhaps `rotatedHead`).

---

There are only two things where I can see that the efficiency can be improved: one is eliminating `kthnode` in the loop, as commented above; the other would be to hang on to the last node when finding the length, so that you don't need to find it a second time in the last few lines. (That would imply changing the factored out method to return an `(int, ListNode)` tuple).

As for time complexity, it's already optimal: linear time. Good job!

Comment: Thanks for the input,My Team lead always suggests to declare variables at top since  most of the projects have huge number of lines and it would be easy for the developers to understand and maintain the code,I kind of curious is this a better practice for large programs

Comment: @MANOJVARMA, as far as I'm concerned, declaring variables at the top is a necessary evil in JavaScript (for reasons I won't go into), but a bad idea in general. I wonder whether maybe there's a miscommunication: perhaps your team lead was talking about laying out a *class* with the *fields* in a predictable place? If a method is so long that you can't see where the variables you're using were declared, it's time to ask whether to refactor it.

Comment: I am sorry if I confused you,I meant the layout of the class.Is it a good practice to declare all the fields at the top of the class which has few methods or can we declare the fields when ever they are required ,since we will be able to track them easily

Comment: It's not uncommon for style guides to mandate an order of each type of member in a class. I think that's something where consistency within a project is the most important guide.

Comment: Could you please clarify how it is possible to track just one variable in the loop? It appears that you still need to know what is the previous value of the pointer somehow.

Comment: @Ilkhd, you *only* need to know what the "previous" value is.

Answer (score 6):

- Using an uppercase name for a variable is a bad practise; should be `rotatedList` or preferably `res` for result or something similar.
- Separate your instantiations with semicolons:

```cs
            ListNode tail = head;
            ListNode rotatedList = null;
            ListNode kthnode = head;
            ListNode kthPrevNode = head;
```

- Your naming of head and tail is confusing. Consider renaming them.
- Use `if (k <= 0 || head == null) return ...;` rather than having a huge if embracing all the method.
- Use preincrements `listLength += 1;` \$\to\$ `++listLength;`. You can also name that variable just `length` (it's obvious we're talking about lists).
- Your variable `kthPrevNode` seems useless. You should remove it.

Answer (score 3):

#### Performance optimization

> ```
> int listLength = 0;
> while (tail != null) {
>     listLength += 1;
>     tail = tail.next;
> }
> ```

Since `head != null` we can start listLength at 1 and keep our tail by checking `tail.next != null` rather than `tail != null`.

```
int listLength = 1;
while (tail.next != null) {
    listLength += 1;
    tail = tail.next;
}
```

Now we no longer have to search for `kthnode` because it's `tail`.

> ```
> // no longer required
> while (kthnode.next != null) {
>     kthnode = kthnode.next;
> }
> kthnode.next = head;
> ```

Instead, we can now append the old head to the tail.

```
tail.next = head;
```

#### Misc

- Since the challenge uses mathematical style variable names, such as `k`, I suggest to rename `listLength` to `n`.
- The challenge states `k` can be asserted non-negative, so I presume `k > 0`. On the other hand, your method is public, so any input could be provided. The challenge does not specify how to handle 'wrong' input. Several ways to perform the argument checks have already been suggested in other answers. One other possibility is to use a sand-box. Left-rotations (`k < 0`) are inversional equivalents of right-rotations. So the following relaxation on `k` deals with any right-rotation, even the ones specified as left-rotation: `k = (k % n + n) % n;`.

Comment: I would follow C# best practices and use meaningful variable names rather than adhere to the challenge's mathematical style names.

Comment: `k` must be non-negative does not me that `k > 0`.  I see nothing that prevents `k = 0` in the challenge.

Comment: 0 is both negative as positive, so non-negative means strict positive k > 0.

Answer (score 2):

There are not much to add to what have already been said about coding style and conventions.

A little optimization on the input check could be that if `head.next == null` then you can leave early as well:

```
  if (head == null || head.next == null || k <= 0)
    return head;
```

Now it's known that there are at least two elements in the list, so calculating the length can be done as:

```
  ListNode runner = head.next;
  int length = 2;

  while (runner.next != null)
  {
    runner = runner.next;
    length++;
  }
```

and with the `length` - the offset from the current head to the new head can be calculated:

```
  int offset = length - k % length;
  if (offset == 0)
    return head;
```

and if `zero` it's time to leave without any changes.

Remaining is to iterate down to the new head, but before that, the current tails next it set to point to head, so the list forms a loop:

```
  runner.next = head;
```

Then loop to the new head:

```
  runner = head;
  while (offset > 1)
  {
    runner = runner.next;
    offset--;
  }
```

and at last the new head and tail are established:

```
  head = runner.next;
  runner.next = null;

  return head;
```

---

Put together it could look like:

```
public ListNode RotateRightHH(ListNode head, int k)
{
  if (head == null || head.next == null || k <= 0)
    return head;

  ListNode runner = head.next;
  int length = 2;

  while (runner.next != null)
  {
    runner = runner.next;
    length++;
  }

  int offset = length - k % length;
  if (offset == 0)
    return head;

  runner.next = head;

  runner = head;
  while (offset > 1)
  {
    runner = runner.next;
    offset--;
  }

  head = runner.next;
  runner.next = null;

  return head;
}
```

What is done in the above differs not much from your version, but the use of a lot fewer variables and maybe some clearer names makes it - IMO - a more easy to follow picture of the method.

Comment: Thanks for the input .This is much clear than my version